# Swagger REST API annotation not working on interface but working on implementation class

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

**This is my Interface ClassA .java**

```
@Path("/"+Paths.STORIES)
@ApiModel(value = "Name API")
@Api(value = "/stories", description = "Name API")
public interface ClassA {
    @GET
    @Path("/"+Paths.STORYID)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Fetch Story by ID", notes = "More notes about this method")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
              @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid ID supplied"),
              @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Invalid ID supplied"),
            })
    public Response getNameFromID(@PathParam("nameId") String nameId);
}
```

**this is my implementation class.**

```
@Singleton
@Component
public class ClassB implements ClassA,InitializingBean{
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public Response getNameFromID(final String nameId) {
        Map NameResponse = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        NameResponse.put("repsonseCode", "200");
        NameResponse.put("errorCode", "");
        return Response.status(200).entity(NameResponse).build();
    }
}
```

**Application-context.xml entry**

```
<bean id="swaggerConfig" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig">
        <property name="resourcePackage" value="com.razak.sample" />
        <property name="version" value="1.0.0" />
        <property name="basePath" value="http://localhost:8080/api" />
        <property name="title" value="Petstore sample app" />
        <property name="description" value="This is a app." />
        <property name="contact" value="apiteam@wordnik.com" />
        <property name="license" value="Apache 2.0 License" />
        <property name="licenseUrl"
            value="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html" />
        <property name="scan" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

web.xml entry

```
    <param-name>swagger.version</param-name>

    <param-value>1.1</param-value>

</init-param>

<init-param>

    <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>

    <param-value>http://localhost:8080/api</param-value>

</init-param>

<init-param>

    <param-name>swagger.security.filter</param-name>

    <param-value>com.wordnik.swagger.sample.util.ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl</param-value>

</init-param>
```

---

```
@Api(value = "/stories", description = "Story API") at class level and 
    @GET
    @Path("/"+Paths.STORYID)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Fetch Story by ID", notes = "More notes about this method")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
              @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid ID supplied"),
              @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Invalid ID supplied"),
            })
```

***When i moved these entry from interface to Implementation class.i m able to access rest endpoints in swagger.swagger is working.but when i placed that annotation in interface itself.it is not working.***

Answer (score 3):

This is an open issue: https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/issues/562

There is also an open issue to document how to override the default scanner: https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/issues/513

I have not tried this out yet, but I think the solution to both the issues is found in this solution:  https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Java-Setup-for-Spring---Jersey---JAX-RS

The trick is to get Swagger to use the ReflectiveJaxrsScanner instead of the DefaultJaxrsScanner.

Answer (score 0):

In swagger-core-1.3.10, @Inherited has been added to the annotations, so I believe this will work now.

Comment: How does that work? You just put an @Inherited on the implementation methods?